Worksheet Index
I have a code that takes data from the user and makes Excel Table.
For each group it supposed to make its own worksheet and it makes it for 'text' data.
But it doesn't make it with image, it puts image from the first lap in every worksheet.
Also after all the laps its deletes an image, but I don't think that it can be an issue.
That's the code:
import xlsxwriter
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import os

num = int(input('Input amount of registers: '))
x = 1
x_ind = np.arange(x)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Registers.xlsx')

for i in range(num):
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    a1 = int(input('Input Power Level 1: '))
    a2 = int(input('Input Min: '))
    a3 = int(input('Input Max: '))
    b1 = int(input('Input Power Level 2: '))
    b2 = int(input('Input Min: '))
    b3 = int(input('Input Max: '))
    c1 = int(input('Input Power Level 3: '))
    c2 = int(input('Input Min: '))
    c3 = int(input('Input Max: '))
    d1 = int(input('Input Power Level 4: ' ))
    d2 = int(input('Input Min: '))
    d3 = int(input('Input Max: '))
    
    row = 0
    
    col1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'red'})
    col2 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color':'green'})
    
    #PW1
    worksheet.write(row, 0, "Input Power Level 1")
    worksheet.write(row, 1, a1)
    worksheet.write(row, 2, "ALARM 1")
    worksheet.write(row, 3, '', col1)
    worksheet.write(row, 4, 'Min Limit')
    worksheet.write(row, 5, a2)
    worksheet.write(row, 6, 'Max Limit')
    worksheet.write(row, 7, a3)
    #Bar1
    pr = 0
    if a2 < 0 and a3 < 0:
        a21 = a2 + (a2*(-1))
        a31 = a3 + (a2*(-1))
        a11 = a1 + (a2*(-1))
        pr = a11/a31 * 100
    elif a2 < 0 and a3 >= 0 and a1 >= 0:
        a21 = a2 + (a2*(-1))
        a31 = a3 + (a2*(-1))
        a11 = a1 + (a2*(-1))
        pr = a11/a31 * 100
    elif a2 < 0 and a3 >= 0 and a1 < 0:
        a21 = a2 + (a2*(-1))
        a31 = a3 + (a2*(-1))
        a11 = a1 + (a2*(-1))
        pr = a11/a31 * 100
    elif a2 >= 0 and a3 >= 0 and a1 >= 0:
        pr = a1/a3 * 100       
    pr = round(pr, 1)
    plt.subplot(1,4,1)
    if a2 < 0 and a3 < 0:
        a22 = a2 + (a2*(-1))
        a32 = a3 + (a2*(-1))
        a12 = a1 + (a2*(-1))
        plt.bar(x_ind, a32, color='white')
        plt.bar(x_ind, a12 , color='purple')
    elif a2 < 0 and a3 >= 0 and a1 >= 0:
        a22 = a2 + (a2*(-1))
        a32 = a3 + (a2*(-1))
        a12 = a1 + (a2*(-1))
        plt.bar(x_ind, a32, color='white')
        plt.bar(x_ind, a12 , color='purple')
    elif a2 < 0 and a3 >= 0 and a1 < 0:
        a22 = a2 + (a2*(-1))
        a32 = a3 + (a2*(-1))
        a12 = a1 + (a2*(-1))
        plt.bar(x_ind, a32, color='white')
        plt.bar(x_ind, a12 , color='purple')
    elif a2 >= 0 and a3 >= 0 and a1 >= 0:
        plt.bar(x_ind, a3, color='white')
        plt.bar(x_ind, a1 , color='purple')

    plt.xticks(x_ind, [a1])
    plt.yticks(x_ind, [pr])
    plt.xlabel('Power Level 1, dBm')
    plt.ylabel('Percent of completion, %')
    row += 1
    
    #PW2
    worksheet.write(row, 0, "Input Power Level 2")
    worksheet.write(row, 1, b1)
    worksheet.write(row, 2, "ALARM 2")
    worksheet.write(row, 3, '', col2)
    worksheet.write(row, 4, 'Min Limit')
    worksheet.write(row, 5, b2)
    worksheet.write(row, 6, 'Max Limit')
    worksheet.write(row, 7, b3)
    #Bar2
    pr = 0
    if b2 < 0 and b3 < 0:
        b21 = b2 + (b2*(-1))
        b31 = b3 + (b2*(-1))
        b11 = b1 + (b2*(-1))
        pr = b11/b31 * 100
    elif b2 < 0 and b3 >= 0 and b1 >= 0:
        b21 = b2 + (b2*(-1))
        b31 = b3 + (b2*(-1))
        b11 = b1 + (b2*(-1))
        pr = b11/b31 * 100
    elif b2 < 0 and b3 >= 0 and b1 < 0:
        b21 = b2 + (b2*(-1))
        b31 = b3 + (b2*(-1))
        b11 = b1 + (b2*(-1))
        pr = b11/b31 * 100
    elif b2 >= 0 and b3 >= 0 and b1 >= 0:
        pr = b1/b3 * 100
    pr = round(pr, 1)
    plt.subplot(1,4,2)
    if b2 < 0 and b3 < 0:
        b22 = b2 + (b2*(-1))
        b32 = b3 + (b2*(-1))
        b12 = b1 + (b2*(-1))
        plt.bar(x_ind, b32, color='white')
        plt.bar(x_ind, b12 , color='purple')
    elif b2 < 0 and b3 >= 0 and b1 >= 0:
        b22 = b2 + (b2*(-1))
        b32 = b3 + (b2*(-1))
        b12 = b1 + (b2*(-1))
        plt.bar(x_ind, b32, color='white')
        plt.bar(x_ind, b12 , color='purple')
    elif b2 < 0 and b3 >= 0 and b1 < 0:
        b22 = b2 + (b2*(-1))
        b32 = b3 + (b2*(-1))
        b12 = b1 + (b2*(-1))
        plt.bar(x_ind, b32, color='white')
        plt.bar(x_ind, b12 , color='purple')
    elif b2 >= 0 and b3 >= 0 and b1 >= 0:
        plt.bar(x_ind, b3, color='white')
        plt.bar(x_ind, b1 , color='purple')

    plt.xticks(x_ind, [b1])
    plt.yticks(x_ind, [pr])
    plt.xlabel('Power Level 2, dBm')
    plt.ylabel('')
    row += 1
    
    #PW3
    worksheet.write(row, 0, "Input Power Level 3")
    worksheet.write(row, 1, c1)
    worksheet.write(row, 2, "ALARM 3")
    worksheet.write(row, 3, '', col1)
    worksheet.write(row, 4, 'Min Limit')
    worksheet.write(row, 5, c2)
    worksheet.write(row, 6, 'Max Limit')
    worksheet.write(row, 7, c3)
    #Bar3 
    pr = 0
    if c2 < 0 and c3 < 0:
        c21 = c2 + (c2*(-1))
        c31 = c3 + (c2*(-1))
        c11 = c1 + (c2*(-1))
        pr = c11/c31 * 100
    elif c2 < 0 and c3 >= 0 and c1 >= 0:
        c21 = c2 + (c2*(-1))
        c31 = c3 + (c2*(-1))
        c11 = c1 + (c2*(-1))
        pr = c11/c31 * 100
    elif c2 < 0 and c3 >= 0 and c1 < 0:
        c21 = c2 + (c2*(-1))
        c31 = c3 + (c2*(-1))
        c11 = c1 + (c2*(-1))
        pr = c11/c31 * 100
    elif c2 >= 0 and c3 >= 0 and c1 >= 0:
        pr = c1/c3 * 100    
    pr = round(pr, 1)
    plt.subplot(1,4,3)
    if c2 < 0 and c3 < 0:
        c22 = c2 + (c2*(-1))
        c32 = c3 + (c2*(-1))
        c12 = c1 + (c2*(-1))
        plt.bar(x_ind, c32, color='white')
        plt.bar(x_ind, c12 , color='purple')
    elif c2 < 0 and c3 >= 0 and c1 >= 0:
        c22 = c2 + (c2*(-1))
        c32 = c3 + (c2*(-1))
        c12 = c1 + (c2*(-1))
        plt.bar(x_ind, c32, color='white')
        plt.bar(x_ind, c12 , color='purple')
    elif c2 < 0 and c3 >= 0 and c1 < 0:
        c22 = c2 + (c2*(-1))
        c32 = c3 + (c2*(-1))
        c12 = c1 + (c2*(-1))
        plt.bar(x_ind, c32, color='white')
        plt.bar(x_ind, c12 , color='purple')
    elif c2 >= 0 and c3 >= 0 and c1 >= 0:
        plt.bar(x_ind, c3, color='white')
        plt.bar(x_ind, c1 , color='purple')

    plt.xticks(x_ind, [c1])
    plt.yticks(x_ind, [pr])
    plt.xlabel('Power Level 3, dBm')
    plt.ylabel('')
    row += 1
    
    #PW4
    worksheet.write(row, 0, "Input Power Level 4")
    worksheet.write(row, 1, d1)
    worksheet.write(row, 2, "ALARM 4")
    worksheet.write(row, 3, '', col2)
    worksheet.write(row, 4, 'Min Limit')
    worksheet.write(row, 5, d2)
    worksheet.write(row, 6, 'Max Limit')
    worksheet.write(row, 7, d3)
    #Bar4
    pr = 0
    if d2 < 0 and d3 < 0:
        d21 = d2 + (d2*(-1))
        d31 = d3 + (d2*(-1))
        d11 = d1 + (d2*(-1))
        pr = d11/d31 * 100
    elif d2 < 0 and d3 >= 0 and d1 >= 0:
        d21 = d2 + (d2*(-1))
        d31 = d3 + (d2*(-1))
        d11 = d1 + (d2*(-1))
        pr = d11/d31 * 100
    elif d2 < 0 and d3 >= 0 and d1 < 0:
        d21 = d2 + (d2*(-1))
        d31 = d3 + (d2*(-1))
        d11 = d1 + (d2*(-1))
        pr = d11/d31 * 100
    elif d2 >= 0 and d3 >= 0 and d1 >= 0:
        pr = d1/d3 * 100    
    pr = round(pr, 1)
    plt.subplot(1,4,4)
    if d2 < 0 and d3 < 0:
        d22 = d2 + (d2*(-1))
        d32 = d3 + (d2*(-1))
        d12 = d1 + (d2*(-1))
        plt.bar(x_ind, d32, color='white')
        plt.bar(x_ind, d12 , color='purple')
    elif d2 < 0 and d3 >= 0 and d1 >= 0:
        d22 = d2 + (d2*(-1))
        d32 = d3 + (d2*(-1))
        d12 = d1 + (d2*(-1))
        plt.bar(x_ind, d32, color='white')
        plt.bar(x_ind, d12 , color='purple')
    elif d2 < 0 and d3 >= 0 and d1 < 0:
        d22 = d2 + (d2*(-1))
        d32 = d3 + (d2*(-1))
        d12 = d1 + (d2*(-1))
        plt.bar(x_ind, d32, color='white')
        plt.bar(x_ind, d12 , color='purple')
    elif d2 >= 0 and d3 >= 0 and d1 >= 0:
        plt.bar(x_ind, d3, color='white')
        plt.bar(x_ind, d1 , color='purple')

    plt.xticks(x_ind, [d1])
    plt.yticks(x_ind, [pr])
    plt.xlabel('Power Level 4, dBm')
    plt.ylabel('')
    
    plt.tight_layout(pad=3.0)
    plt.savefig('Registers.png')
    
    row += 2
    worksheet.insert_image(row, 0, 'Registers.png')
            
workbook.close()  


It might not answer your question, but I would use XlsxWriter for charting.https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_charts.html

The issue is that the program is overwriting the 'Registers.png' image with a file of the same name, each time it goes through the loop. XlsxWriter doesn't read the image until the file/workbook is closed and at that point the image has been overwritten.
A solution would be to give each unique image a unique name like this:
    # ...
    image_name = f"registers{i}.png"
    plt.savefig(image_name)
    row += 2

Two other suggestions:

It should be possible to write the matplotlib image to a memory buffer and add that to the XlsxWriter file without the need for a temporary physical image file.
It would be possible to avoid matplotlib and use Excel/XlsxWriter charts to plot the data instead.

